# Using Linked SQL Servers from a different server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 3 machines that are involved in running a SQL script:

1. JumpBox - A machine that serves as a stable point for automation to run.
2. ReportBox - A machine that holds reporting databases and logic. Running SQL Server 2008 R2
3. OLTPBox - A machine that contains an OLTP database. Running SQL Server 2014

Because OLTPBox is an unstable test environment (it is torn down regularly and rebuilt), we need to do as much work as possible outside of that context. So I have a SQL script (call it `InsertScript.sql`) that basically does the following:

`INSERT INTO testresults 
 VALUES (SELECT * from OLTPBox.prod.dbo.results)`

OLTPBox in the script is a linked server.

The above script is wrapped in a SQLCMD call that is run on JumpBox:

`SQLCMD -i .\InsertScript.sql -S ReportBox -D Reporting`

However when I run this, I get the following error:

`Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Server OLTPBox, Line 1
Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.`

The context I'm running as on JumpBox exists as a DBO to all of the appropriate databases, and all 3 of the servers, so I'm not sure why it's losing context on trying to use the Linked Server. All three of the machines are on the same domain, and are in fact even in the same subnet (so they authenticate using the same DC).

What's going on here, why is the login context being lost?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your SPN's on all SQL Servers involved.

I usually do the following:

```
setspn –A MSSQLSvc/myservername.fqdn:instancename DOMAIN\SQLServiceAccount
setspn –A MSSQLSvc/myservername.fqdn:port DOMAIN\SQLServiceAccount
setspn –A MSSQLSvc/myservername:instancename DOMAIN\SQLServiceAccount
setspn –A MSSQLSvc/myservername:port DOMAIN\SQLServiceAccount
```

That should catch most of the possible ways to connect

You can check if it's working by having a look at the `sys.dm_exec_connections` table. Look for `Kerberos` under `auth_scheme`. It might take a few minutes to kick in, if not try restarting the services connecting to your SQL.